# Replacing the old content of a <td>,with the new content returned from ajax using td's id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

in that i have a coloumn status,this is my jsp below:

```
<s:iterator value="uploadList" var="m" status="status">
            <tr>
            <td><s:property value="%{#m.uploadDate}" /></td>
            <td id="status<s:property value="%{#status.index}" /> "><s:property value="%{#m.status}" /></td> <<--this is the status coloumn td with id..
            <td>tbd</td>
            <td id="button<s:property value="%{#status.index}" /> "><img src="images/refresh.png" title="Refresh" class="refresh" id="ref<s:property value="%{#status.index}" />" onclick="refreshRecord(<s:property value="%{#m.fileId}" />);"></td> <<--this is the refresh icon
```

onclick of refresh img i am calling ajax its giving new status value which is in variable status in ajax,and i have this status column id in the variable statusId in ajax:

this is my ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".refresh").click(function(){
            var currentId=$(this).attr('id');
               var fileId=file;
               $.ajax({
               type:'post',
                url:'checkStatusAndNumRecs',
               data:{fileId:fileId},
                success:function(data)
               {
                    var obj=data.split(':');
                    var status=obj[0];
                    var numrecs=obj[1];
                    var statusId=currentId.replace("ref","status"); <<---this is the status col td's id.
                    $(statusId).html(status);
                    alert("after"+currentId);
               },
```

problem is i am using this to replace old content with the new content like this:
`$(statusId).html(status);` where statusId is the id of status col  and status is the new status that ajax returned.but its not replacing..
please help me in this.
thankyou in advance.

Comment: what error are you getting??

Comment: i am not getting any error its not replacing with the new status..

Comment: @MarounMaroun ok sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the `id` correct, but you need to use it as an id-selector when passing it to jQuery

```
$('#' + statusId).html(status);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

If you use `id` to replace old content

```
$('#'+statusId).empty().append(status);
```

If you use `classname` to replace old content

```
$('.'+statusId).empty().append(status);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#'+statusId).html(status);
```

reference **[html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)**

Answer (score 0):

I think you may change for this :

```
  $("#"+statusId).html(status);
```

To ref the ID.